# Common character to indicate error has occured

Tags: c, char

Typically in a function that returns an integer, `-1` is used to indicate to the user/programmer that a error has occurred in the program. e.g. A program may return `-1` instead of the index of where a word starts in a string if the word cannot be found in the string.

So my question is, what should you return from a function that returns a character instead?
In other words, is there a common character that most programmers use like `-1` to detect when an error has occurred?

---

It may be subjective to the scenario of course so lets say you created a program that converts a digit into its corresponding character:

```
char digitToCh (int digit)
{

    if ( digit < 0 ) // If digit is negative, return ?
        return '?';

    int n = intLen (digit);

    if ( n > 1 )
        digit /= power (10, n - 1);

    return (char) (((int) '0') + digit);
}
```

If the digit is negative, what error character code would seem appropriate. This example is quite arbitrary but I'm just trying to make it simpler to express.

Comment: Just as a note: To get the leftmost digit of your number, you could just use `while (digit > 9) digit /= 10;` This saves you from determining the integer length as well as the power calculation.

Comment: @Mario Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Oh, and one more (for readability): You don't have to cast the character `'0'` to an `int`. There's already an implicit conversion (due to the addition with an `int`). Just keep the cast to `char` to avoid compiler warnings about possible truncation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such reserved character. In fact, it is the absence of such common character that caused character-oriented I/O functions to change their return type to `int`.

The trick with returning an `int` is important when you must retain the full range of character return values. In your case, however, only the ten digit characters are valid, so returning character zero `'\0'` is a valid option:

```
char digitToCh (int digit) {
    if (digit < 0) return '\0';
    ...
}
```

You can check the error like this:

```
char nextDigit = digitToCh(someInt);
if (!nextDigit) {
    // The next digit is invalid
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this maybe cause confusion if I wanted to use `0` since `\0` would equate to it?

Comment: But `\0` is different from `'0'`, as the latter is `48`.

Comment: @user2849447 If I understand the intention behind your code, the only valid returns are characters `'0'` through `'9'`, with codes from 48 to 58. `'\0'` has the code of zero, so it can be used as a special value in this situation.

Comment: @alk Okay, just to clarify, so `\0` will print nothing, and `0` will be printed normally?

Comment: @user2849447 Zero by itself (i.e. `0`) is confusing. C has three zeros - the regular zero `0`, the character zero `'\0'` (note the single quotes and a slash) and a digit zero `'0'` (note the single quotes). The first two are the same for most purposes. The third one is different - it is an alternative representation of number 48.

Answer (score 1):

Make the function return an `int` instead of a `char` and also use `-1` to indicate an error.

This way it is done by [`fgetc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) for example.
.

Comment: So basically returning their ASCII codes and converting them into chars else where?

Comment: @user2849447 `char` are 8bit integers, that's why in fact you do not need to change your code at all, besides the function's return value and adding the return of the `-1` for the error case.